# Divisão entre valores de colunas e linhas usando pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Criei uma pivot table contendo alguns valores, *porém não sei se é necessário utilizar pivot table neste caso* segue abaixo uma amostra dos resultados:

```
             Valor ajuste                                          \
Data posicao   2017-05-30   2017-05-31   2017-06-01    2017-06-02   
Ativo                                                               
FUT AUD        -8478.0000  273771.0000   82449.0000  -177507.0000   
FUT BGI        75900.0000  -60720.0000   95634.0000    13662.0000   
FUT CAD        59314.5000  177849.0000  -40956.3000   -24179.4000
```

Preciso realizar uma divisão entre estes valores e os valores do dataframe a seguir:

```
          Data   Patrimonio
0   2017-05-30  50451168.08
1   2017-05-31  51057040.07
2   2017-06-01  51641619.65
```

Em cada data é necessário realizar uma divisão do **Valor ajuste pelo Patrimonio**. Quais são as maneiras de fazê-la?

OBS.: O resultado da divisão irá ser utilizado para outro cálculo posterior a esse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,28,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,28,size=(4, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(( df_1.shape[0] , df_1.shape[1] )) , columns=list('ABCD'))

for data in range(len(df_1.columns)):
    df_3[ list(df_1.columns)[data] ] =  df_1[ list(df_1.columns)[data] ] / df_2.iloc[data]['A']
df_3
```